# Babel, ES6, Webpack - Destructuring of destructured imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

Working on app that has begun as a `create-react-app`.

In my code, I have a multiple named imports, written like this:

```
import {Banana, Apple} from 'fruits'
```

> The `fruits` module is a folder with `index.js` in it, that has `export {Banana} from './banana'` somewhere in it. That `./banana` exports an object `Banana = {bite: ()=>{}}`.
>
> So I am expecting `Foo` to be that object exported in `banana`.

Now, I'm trying to do something like

```
const {bite} = Banana;
```

The bundle builds successfully, but when I run it - it fails, says it can not get `bite` from `undefined`.

And what is truly weird for me - it did not happen before, but then it just started to happen, with no particular reason. But sometimes it happened with Jest, too - it failed to import that `bite` from undefined.

Right now I'm just doing

```
import {Banana} from 'fruits/banana';
import {Apple} from 'fruits/apple';
```

and it works just fine this way. However, I want it to be

```
import {Banana, Apple} from 'fruits';
const {bite} = Banana;
```

Any ideas on what could have caused that?

What should I do to keep the code the way I want (see above)?

Comment: Do you export Banana?

Comment: @IgorAlemasow, I do.It works just fine if I directly import Banana from 'fruits/banana'. Or if I use `Banana.bite` directly instead of `const bite = {Banana}`

Comment: Everything looks fine, here is fully working example https://codesandbox.io/s/7wvvvo88kx . Can you optimise it with your code,  maybe there is some spelling error in your code?

Answer (score 1):

After all, turned out it was a **circular dependency issue** in our very own specific setup (webpack sometimes returns undefined for scripts that either directly or not refer to scripts they are used in.

We had an `index.js` script in every folder (e.g. `fruits`) and one of modules used another one (e.g. `Banana` used an import of `Pineapple` from `fruits`, instead of referring to it directly, `fruits/Pineapple`)

This issue, once for all, taught me to use [circular-dependency-plugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin) in my every webpack build (and avoid circular dependencies)